# nix operating systems for azure cloud services

Tags: linux, windows, azure, azure-cloud-services

It seems like the operating systems available for cloud services are only limited to windows OS'es. I checked the 'configure' tab in the azure management console. It only listed Windows Server in the operating system family.

Is there a way to configure the cloud service to use linux OS'es?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Cloud Services is a PaaS (Platform As A Service) offering.  The PaaS uses a customized version of Windows Server internally, so unlike the Azure IaaS offering Linux is not available; that said, with the PaaS you don't manage the VMs directly.  Code properly written for the PaaS should be OS-agnostic to the point that there isn't a reason the underlying systems need to be running Linux.

You can run application [in a variety of languages](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/) on Azure Cloud Services.  Just click a language, then click "Compute" in the docs and find the section for Cloud Services.  [Here is an example](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-php-create-web-role/) of creating a web role on ACS to run PHP.